# How to calculate user scores based on 3 variables to assign an appropriate text label?

Tags: 7, views, users, display-suite, entities

I need to calculate a score for users in D7 based on 3 variables and then assign an appropriate text label and a CSS class.

So, using data from Voting API, time ago joined, and number of nodes published, it needs to select and display one of 15 text labels such as "Promising newcomer, reliable veteran, etc".

Given that I am a site builder with limited PHP skills, where should I start? Should I setup 15 different rules to set a value on a list field?

Before investing time in Computed Field, Display Suite Custom Field or Views PHP, I would love advice from the Drupal community.

Looking for something similar to [SE badges](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Comment: for Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Drupal 7, but needs to have an upgrade path to D8 in the medium term.

Comment: I could setup 15 different rules to set a value on a list field but is it the best way?

Comment: `I need to calculate a score` what action exactly triggers this calculation? (when do you need to do the calculation?)

Comment: Actually, calculating a score is really unnecessary, I just need the text label.

Comment: I've settled on using Rules and Flag as the foundation for programatically setting labels/badges.

Comment: Decided Flag was overkill. I've settled on using Rules and a List Field as the foundation for programatically setting labels/badges.

The field will specify 15 text options and classes, not editable by users.

The Rules will be based on this template:
TRIGGER After adding new content OR votes are calculated OR 
CONDITIONS Evaluate votes, Data comparison for date joined, Not sure about how to evaluate node count yet (Stats or Views???)
ACTION Flag a user > with appropriate text label AND schedule component evaluation e.g. 1 year after date joined

I hope it works.

Comment: @NoSssweat : IMO the [goal](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) of this question seems mostly to be related to calculations ... (after you get them right, leave it to themers to visiualize them ...).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you're right `Promising newcomer, reliable veteran, etc".`, I totally misunderstood the Q. I was confused by labels thing, was thinking field label, lol, rather than user level.

Comment: @NoSssweat : good to know we're on the same page now ... I might (later on) post a related question for suggestions about visualising (theming, reporting, charting, etc) achieved [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) ...

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer is to trigger [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Actions based on a combination of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Events that happen ***asynchronously***, and optionally after they were ***repeated*** multiple times. Which also requires some type of recording of the progress being made. Pretty challenging specs, but there is a solution (module) for it, as further explained below.

## Goals module

You may want to look at the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer) as a possible alternative. To start using it only requires typical administration tasks (configuration), though it does come with various hooks also for custom module development (if you want to).

Since the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module is entity based, it has out-of-the-box integrations with modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), etc.

## Requirements mapping

> I need to calculate a score for users in D7 based on 3 variables and then assign an appropriate text label and a CSS class.

**calculate**: that's what [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) will do for you, by *recording* the progress made on the completion of each *task* required to reach a *goal*.

**3 variables**: that sounds like 3 *tasks* to be completed to achieve 1 *goal*.

**assign an appropriate text label**: you can optionally attach a (custom) image to each goal. The goals completed by a user, can be shown on a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) block included with [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals), with title "Your completed goals".

> So, using data from Voting API, time ago joined, and number of nodes published, it needs to select and display one of 15 text labels such as "Promising newcomer, reliable veteran, etc".

**using data from...**: if you can think of a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) ***Event*** to discover these events, you use the appropriate Rules ***Action*** (provided by [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals)) to record progress on the completion of a *task*. E.g. if 1 such task would be to "create 10 nodes of type XYZ", then each time such nodes are saved (there is a Rules Event for it!), then [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) will *record* so. And if 10 such nodes were recorded, the task is considered completed. And if all tasks of a specific goal or completed, then the goal is reached.

Here is a screenprint of a rule to record a task activity about posting comments:

[image]

**15 text labels**: that sounds like 15 *goals* you'd have to configure using the admin interface of the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (no custom coding involved).

## More details

For more details about the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module, refer to my answer to "[How to implement gamification in a Drupal site and award incentives?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/168)".